# Is there a way to upload a file from view in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I know that you can upload files using a ModelForm in django, but is there a way to do it through a view instead? For example, after a form is completed, I want an automated process that will create a file (based on input from the form) and upload it to my media directory, but the file itself isn't submitted by the user who is submitting the form.  So in the form submission view, I would like to write code that generates a non-text file (video) and uploads it to my media directory.  My media files are hosted on amazon S3 if that makes a difference.  Is this possible in django, and if so, how?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Django views are python. and yes, it's possible to upload things and save files in python. To upload to S3, the easiest way is to use `django-storages` and use their storage engine.

Comment: I have used boto, how does django-storages compare?

Comment: @Victor'Chris'Cabral django storages ties boto into django by defining django storage engines.. meaning you can use all of django's file interfaces. a file field that uses remote storage, or all static files using remote storage.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I was overthinking it and making it a lot harder than it needed to be.  I am able to upload files now, however I'm still unable to serve my purpose of getting it to upload the output file of an ffmpeg video conversion.

Answer (score 0):

So I put in an answer to my original question:

```
input = "blah file input"
filename = "media/filename.txt"
storage = default_storage.open(filename, 'w+')
storage.write(input)
storage.close()
```